# Setting background image without stretch the image using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to set the background image using CSS but the original image is stretched.
How do I keep the original image size and set the background for the entire page at the same time?

```
 body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(background.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

The original image is: [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWPck.png)

And the result is: [Resultent Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW1r1.png)

The difference is the background in my web is larger than the original.

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to remove `background-size: cover`,
then all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options regarding the background image and size. 
For your needs you can check this [W3c](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and try the different options you can apply.

Remember that since you apply CSS to your Body, all your pages will "follow" those rules. But some of your pages might have different height from the others.

The result also, depends on the screen resolution of the client.
You have to deside what is your desired result in all screen resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just remove, `background-size:cover;`
  Now let's see what does that mean,

- `background-size`

  Because `background-size` CSS property specifies the size of the
  background images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or
  only partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.
- `cover`

  A keyword that is the inverse of `contain`(*`contain` value specifies that regardless of the size of the containing box, the background image should be scaled so that each side is as large as possible while not exceeding the length of the corresponding side of the container*). `cover` scales the image as large
  as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get
  squished). The image "covers" the entire `width` or `height` of the
  container. When the image and container have different dimensions,
  the image is clipped either left/right or top/bottom.

To get much identification just try [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/)

For the more reference on [background-size:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Answer (score 0):

remove background-size: cover;

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `background-size:cover;` & set width of image to your requirement.
`background-size:cover;`stretches the image to full background.

or

Please change your image extension from .png to .jpeg or .jpg because .png always stretches your image and after that the css property u have defined earlier will work properly.

Comment: Downvoted because the information on PNG is simply wrong.  I recommend WEBP because it supports all the features of both PNG and JPG while being smaller than either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I found the problem.
the source image is open with a zoom of 35% therefore when I set the backgroud it stretch to 100%.

```
  body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(background.png);
  background-size: 60% 60%;
  background-position: center center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
.your-class {
   background-image: url(background.png);
   /* Required Height */
   height: 800px; 

   /* Center and scale the image nicely */
   background-position: center  !important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat   !important;
   background-size: cover   !important;
}
```