# Set background image size using CSS without stretching

Tags: html, css

I want to set some background image size using CSS.

I am able to set the size using the below css codes. I have been reading up on css formatting at w3schools, and also referred to the below [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491166/setting-background-image-without-stretch-the-image-using-css):

```
background: url([[pix:theme|cat/default]]) no-repeat center bottom; 
background-size: 180px 200px;
```

I have tried all the methods, including contain and cover. However i keep getting the image stretched and blurred. How can I do this without blurring the image? FYI original image size is `128Kb 1210x1643px`

Comment: Share your code please. @ktiwari

Comment: How do you expect to resize the image without stretching (or squashing) it?

Comment: `1210 x 1643` and `180 x 200` do not have the same aspect ratio so of course the image will be stretched. `180 x 244` would be closer.

Comment: isn't `1210x1643` more pixelated than `180x200` and have better view of the image? 

What would your suggestion be on the sizing to get clearer image?

Answer (score 0):

Sooo,

You cannot stretch the image without bluring or loosing quality.
I recommend you to have a high quality image and put the image in a kinda matching background-colored div.

Then you can use either [media-quires](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) or some JavaScript to keep the image as big as possible.

Also it would be helpful to see some of your code, or have a better description what you are trying to do. :)

Comment: this is my code for the image: 

`background: url([[pix:theme|cat/default]])
 no-repeat center bottom; 
background-size: 180px 200px; `

with the background-size, i tried percentage, contain & cover parameters but image is appears still blurred

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?